# AWS/Step start_execution() multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have the following code to trigger a step function.

```
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn=stateMachineArn,
    name=name,
    input={'id': 'my-id'},
    headers={'mode': 'normal'}
)
```

What would happen if I trigger the the same step function with the same "name". Does the existing step function restart, and everything start from fresh inside the step function instance?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly detailed in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html):

> `StartExecution` is idempotent for `STANDARD` workflows. For a `STANDARD` workflow, if `StartExecution` is called with the same name and input as a running execution, the call will succeed and return the same response as the original request. If the execution is closed or if the input is different, it will return a `400 ExecutionAlreadyExists` error. Names can be reused after 90 days.
>
> `StartExecution` is not idempotent for `EXPRESS` workflows.